# I want to make a table without summary function

Tags: r

```
x=iris[,1:4]
summary(x)
```

How can I make this?
I use this:

```
Sepal.Length=c("Min.   :4.300","1st Qu.:5.100","Median :5.800","Mean   :5.843","3rd Qu :6.400","Max.   :7.900")  
Sepal.Width=c("Min.   :2.000","1st Qu.:2.800","Median :3.000","Mean   :3.057","3rd Qu :3.300","Max.   :4.400")  
Petal.Length=c("Min.   :1.000","1st Qu.:1.600","Median :4.350","Mean   :3.758","3rd Qu :5.100","Max.   :6.900")  
Petal.Width=c("Min.   :0.100","1st Qu.:0.300","Median :1.300","Mean   :1.199","3rd Qu :1.800","Max.   :2.500")  

kk=cbind(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width)  

as.table(kk)
```

but It has row names `(A,B,C,D,E,F)`

![enter image description here][2]

How can i delete that letters??

Or Does any different ways to make this table??

Please Help

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve with the table you are trying to build and why you are _not_ using the `summary` function? (Since all values are stored as `character`s in your table you can't easily access them it doesn't seem to make much sense building a table that way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kk <- as.table(kk)  
dimnames(kk)[[1]] <- rep("", nrow(kk))

## Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width   Petal.Length  Petal.Width  
## Min.   :4.300 Min.   :2.000 Min.   :1.000 Min.   :0.100
## 1st Qu.:5.100 1st Qu.:2.800 1st Qu.:1.600 1st Qu.:0.300
## Median :5.800 Median :3.000 Median :4.350 Median :1.300
## Mean   :5.843 Mean   :3.057 Mean   :3.758 Mean   :1.199
## 3rd Qu :6.400 3rd Qu :3.300 3rd Qu :5.100 3rd Qu :1.800
## Max.   :7.900 Max.   :4.400 Max.   :6.900 Max.   :2.500
```

Comment: @user3686685, what do you need?

Comment: Whats is `xx`? And what is your question? Maybe you want to make it as a new question?

Comment: i=1

while(i<=4){  
  
xx[1,i]=min(x[,i])

xx[2,i]=quantile(x[,i])[2]

xx[3,i]=median(x[,i])

xx[4,i]=mean(x[,i])

xx[5,i]=quantile(x[,i])[4]

xx[6,i]=max(x[,i])

i=i+1

dimnames(xx)=list(c("Min", "1st Qu", "median","mean","3rd Qu","Max"), names(x))

dimnames(xx)[[1]]=rep("",nrow(xx))

options(digits=4)
  
}

print(xx)


I want to upload screenshots but i can't because of reputation sorry 

Thanks to your help, I can make above code, but It has a little problem. 
Can i put characters in front of numbers?

now values are 5.100, 5.800, 
but i want to make 1st Qu.:5.100, Median  :5.800

Comment: yeah i will do thatㅜㅜ

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930786/how-can-i-put-characthers-in-front-of-numbers

Comment: this is my new question Thank you