# How can i put characthers in front of numbers?

Tags: r

```
xx=matrix(,ncol=4,nrow=6)
x=iris[,1:4]   

i=1
while(i<=4){
  xx[1,i]=min(x[,i])
  xx[2,i]=quantile(x[,i])[2]
  xx[3,i]=median(x[,i])
  xx[4,i]=mean(x[,i])
  xx[5,i]=quantile(x[,i])[4]
  xx[6,i]=max(x[,i])
  i=i+1
  dimnames(xx)=list(c("Min", "1st Qu", "median","mean","3rd Qu","Max"), names(x))
  dimnames(xx)[[1]]=rep("",nrow(xx)) 
  options(digits=4) 
}
print(xx)
```

I want to upload screenshots but i can't because of reputation sorry. Thanks to your help, I can make above code, but it has a little problem. Can I put characters in front of numbers?

Now values are `5.100`, `5.800`, but I want to make it like: `1st Qu.:5.100`, `Median :5.800`

Thank you

Comment: What is `xx`? It is not reproducible. You probably need to add `xx <- matrix(NA, 6, 4)` before the loop

Comment: oh, xx=iris[,1:4] and also you are right. I made the matrix before

Comment: Oh sorry
xx=matirx(,ncol=4,nrow=6)
x=iris[,1:4]

Comment: Edit your question, not comments

Comment: @user3686685 please remove all extra comments. Welcome to SO . You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: what if you just removed `dimnames(xx)[[1]]=rep("",nrow(xx))` ?

Comment: @user3686685 do you wan to recode `summary` function?

Comment: @agstudy Yes right I want to make summary(iris[,1:4]) without using summary function. I'm not good at speaking and reading English, So It's hard to read R help.

Comment: @user3686685, just remove `dimnames(xx)[[1]]=rep("",nrow(xx))` like @flodel said and your question is solved

Comment: @DavidArenburg No...It's a little bit different, I have to make exactly same as summary[iris[,1:4]  I want to explain more but i can't speak english well ㅜㅜㅜ

Comment: you could potentialy add `paste0` to each line. For example, Instead of `xx[1,i]=min(x[,i])`, put `xx[1,i]=paste0("Min.   :",min(x[,i]))` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here one way to "recode" , `summary` function.

I am trying to use `xxapply` functions. There are powfrul tools and are the standard way to do things. Avoid loop in R , specially for their side effect.

```
## helper function
Quantile <- function(which,...)
  function(...)quantile(...)[which]
## init functions and columns 
funcs <- 
 c(min,Quantile(2),median,mean,Quantile(4),max)
names <- 
c("Min   ", "1st Qu", "Median","mean  ","3rd Qu","Max   ")
## a summary of o column
summary_vector <- 
function(x)
 mapply(function(n,f)paste(n,format(f(x),digits=2),sep=':'),
   names,funcs)
## apply it for all columns   
sapply(iris[,1:4],summary_vector)
```

Which gives this output :

```
       Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width 
Min    "Min   :4.3" "Min   :2"   "Min   :1"   "Min   :0.1"
1st Qu "1st Qu:5.1" "1st Qu:2.8" "1st Qu:1.6" "1st Qu:0.3"
Median "Median:5.8" "Median:3"   "Median:4.3" "Median:1.3"
mean   "mean  :5.8" "mean  :3.1" "mean  :3.8" "mean  :1.2"
3rd Qu "3rd Qu:6.4" "3rd Qu:3.3" "3rd Qu:5.1" "3rd Qu:1.8"
Max    "Max   :7.9" "Max   :4.4" "Max   :6.9" "Max   :2.5"
```

Comparing to `summary(iris[,1:4])` :

```
 Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width   
 Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100  
 1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:2.800   1st Qu.:1.600   1st Qu.:0.300  
 Median :5.800   Median :3.000   Median :4.350   Median :1.300  
 Mean   :5.843   Mean   :3.057   Mean   :3.758   Mean   :1.199  
 3rd Qu.:6.400   3rd Qu.:3.300   3rd Qu.:5.100   3rd Qu.:1.800  
 Max.   :7.900   Max.   :4.400   Max.   :6.900   Max.   :2.500
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I print similar output to the console, from `cgwtools::mystat` . (`numdig` is a function argument defining the precision to display)

```
 allstats <- data.frame(cbind(min = min(x), max = max(x), 
        mean = mean(x), median = median(x), sdev = sd(x), skew = theskew(x), 
        kurtosis = thekurt(x)), row.names = "")
    if (printit) {
        print(format(allstats[1:4], digits = numdig))
        print(format(allstats[5:7], digits = numdig))
    }
```